# Mixing pieces of Phonegap to native app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, titanium

We have a requirement where we need to generate FORM like UIs in some areas of our app. For this we are considering writing a layer using phonegap / titanium etc so that the same can be used for iOS / Android. With Phonegap I understand that I can include a CDVWebView using Cleaver that will display all the forms.

My question is, is there any way to embed a custom native view ( say a custom UIView which shows a graph ) inside the phonegap view?

Comment: I am confused... are you asking how to include a graph in appcelerator or how to create a native form in appcelerator?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I need to be able to dynamically generate forms which may have simple layouts with labels, text fields, buttons along with complex views which need to be plugged in from the native side. However I want to be able to integrate this crossplatform module onto my native apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this as a plugin, so that something on your PhoneGap view triggers the display of the native view, but you can't really embed it in the phonegap view because the phonegap view is just rendered html inside a webview. What you'd get is something like a child view or popover.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Would you recommend any other framework or workaround that you could think of? I think Titanium can do this since it renders everything as native ( correct me if I'm wrong ), but I guess we can't seem to mix pieces of titanium code in our xcode project.

Comment: @MahadevanSreenivasan I don't have any experience with Titanium, but I wouldn't be surprised if it did let you do this, because of it compiling native code - but you still might have to do it via some sort of plugin interface.